# Is there a way to get the powerline effect with mintty unders windows 10 bash?

Tags: fonts, cygwin, mintty

I know I can install zsh under bash, but for various reasons I'm stuck with mingw.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Anyway, you really mess in terms. Both zsh and bash are shells, programs which manage input and output from/to the user and interpret commands, MinGW is a minimalist GNU for Windows, a set of compilers and development toolchains for compiling source code designed for Linux on Windows and MinTTY is a terminal application, an interface between the user and shell. You're mixing everything together.

Comment: Anyway, just set the right (patched) font in MinTTY and you're good to go. I expect that you set up the powerline in bash already.

Comment: Actually the MinGW came with Git for Windows and includes mintty.  It does come with some basic fonts and coloring, but not to the level I'd like to see.  I'm not using it for compiling, but rather for git only, so that's why the question.